# Are all complete groups abelian?

Tags: abelian-groups

Hi: Let $G$ be a group and $G'$ it's commutator subgroup. Then $G > G' > 1$ is a series of normal subgroups of $G$. Suppose $G$ is complete. Then, if I'm not wrong, $Aut(G)$ is the stabilizer of that series. But then, by a theorem, $Aut(G)$ is nilpotent of class <= 1, that is $Aut(G)' = 1$ and $Aut(G)$ is abelian. Now, as $G$ is complete, $Aut(G) \cong G$. But then $G$ is abelian! What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
This is from Rotman's An Introduction to the Theory of Groups, 4th edition, p.165: 
Definition. Let $G= G_0 > G_1 > ... > G_r= 1$ be a series of normal subgroups  a group $G$. An automorphism $\alpha \in Aut(G)$ stabilizes this series if $\alpha(G_i x) = G_i x$ for all $i$ and all $x \in G_{i-1}$. The stabilizer $A$ of this series is the subgroup 
$A =$ {$\alpha \in Aut(G): \alpha$ stabilizes the series} $\leq Aut(G)$.

Theorem 7.19. The stabilizer A of a series of normal subgroups $G = G_0 > G_1 > ... > G_r = 1$ is a nilpotent group of class $\leq r - 1$.

Comment: Complete groups are centerless by **definition**. Abelian groups aren't, ever. What do you mean by $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is the stabilizer of that series? You're just blabbing words out here.

Comment: Also, please state the theorem that you are referring to.

Comment: Your comment was more useful without the last line. OP has a sincere question and is aware that s/he is failing to understand something. Criticism is unlikely to help.

Comment: @jdc Criticism is what helps, really. It's not a bad thing.

Comment: I guess everyone's different, but I think the first part was constructive criticism and already makes the useful points without the harshness of "blabbing."

Comment: I added a definition and a theorem in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I added a definition of stabilizer and a a theorem, all from Rotman's An Introduction to the Theory of Groups, 4th edition.